# Replace values of unmatched index with 'Other' python3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, series

This is the original series. I'm trying to replace values of the non top 2 in the series with 'Other'.

**Original Series(ser3):**

```
 b    8
 c    6
 a    5 
 h    4
 g    2
 d    2
 f    2
 e    1
```

This is my extracted top 2.

**Top 2:**

```
t2 = ((ser3.value_counts().head(2)))

b    8
c    6
```

**Expected Output:**

```
 b    8
 c    6
 a    Other 
 h    Other
 g    Other
 d    Other
 f    Other
 e    Other
```

How can I do that? I do not want to convert to dictionary and replace the values by indexing. I prefer to do it by Series. I tried using .isin, but my code gives me an error.

```
 a[a[~a.isin(t2)].index]='Other'
```

The above gives me an error.

Comment: Are you sure you want to mix dtypes like this?

Answer (score 0):

You are close, need select `t2.index` and remove outer `ser3[]`:

```
ser3[~ser3.isin(t2.index)]='Other'
```